# Lenovo Z50-70 dual boot Ubuntu GNOME 16.04/Windows 10 fails to suspend

Tags: nvidia, suspend, laptop, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Z50-70 (NVIDIA and Intel) RAM and swap 8 GB, with dual boot, Ubuntu GNOME 16.04/Windows 10 and every time I try to suspend it, it first suspends normally but then I can not resume successfully. It shows me the screen where I left off but it is completely frozen, and I cannot do anything else than reboot with the button.

With Windows 10 suspend works normally.

I have tried suspending from virtual console with no success and I have tried with Intel and NVIDIA (both drivers prop and open source) graphics with no success.

I want to be able to close my laptop and have it suspend normally and the continue working after resuming.

EDIT: I tried SuperMohit's solution and:

When I run `nvidia-settings` I get this:

ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

** (nvidia-settings:8554): WARNING **: PRIME: Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/prime-supported" (No such file or directory)
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should have been installed along
       with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and
       will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and
       descriptions.

And then the window opens, but I do not see any "PRIME Profiles" tab, only  "Rules", and "Profile" tabs, with nothing in them.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on another forum.
The problem is with two GPU's, Intel & Nvidia. If Nvdia is the default GPU, suspend and hibernate will have issues.

Step1 : Run `nvidia-settings` on terminal.

Step2 : In "PRIME Profiles" tab, select the GPU as "Intel" instead of "NVIDIA".

Step3 : Save and restart your machine.

I tested this on 14.0.4 and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and edited my question with what happened.

Comment: Are you using the proprietary graphic driver of Nvidia? If not then try using that and then run the command.

Comment: I was not, but I changed it to the propietary one: version 340.98 from nvidia-340

and have the same message posted on the edit in the question. Any other suggestion is welcomed. Is there like another way to COMPLETLEY disable the Nvidia card so maybe it will only use the Intel one so there will be no problems?